# What is the JAMstack web development architecture?

Tags: web, web-architecture

I keep seeing references to **JAMstack** web development architecture.

From the web page [Jamstack.org](https://jamstack.org/) it is not obvious how JAMstack is different from the common **JavaScript SPA** frontend with **REST API** backend architecture.

What is the key difference?

Comment: The answer to this question is the very first hit on Google for "jamstack". I suppose you weren't feeling lucky. As a user with nearly 10k reputation, I would have expected better. How did this stay open for so long?

Comment: Uh, yeah. General reference questions that can be answered by typing an obvious phrase into Google and looking at the first result should probably be closed.

Comment: Right on Cody! You should consider deleting your top voted answer "Declare a Const Array in C#" because MSDN article from 2004 is just as good as your answer and would be the top result if not for SO. :) Seriously, I answered this question because I too was looking for more information about Jamstack and this was the only question on SO. I suppose I should just go back to lurking.

Comment: @Sint : It looks like literally every interesting question ends up getting closed on SO these days, often before anyone has the chance to answer... while the site just keeps getting flooded with poor question answers that aren't closed at all. So... sad...

Comment: For example I did read official web sites for Jamstack. But it theirs site, they can write whatever they want there - that it is the best approach in the world... so I came here to SO as it is for me (often) trustworthy source of Information to search for reviews based on critical thinking and experience with other possible options...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**J**avascript Heavy front end - **A**PIs for everything else - templated **M**arkup

[jamstack.org](https://jamstack.org/) is the canonical site with examples and explanation

The key thing that differentiates JAMstack from other architectures is the middle part. APIs for every back end function means that backend can be spread out/scaled with ease.

EDIT: I should add that the term was coined by a CDN company Netlify which stands to benefit from a wider adoption of the architecture.

Comment: Wait a second. I don't understand how APIs differentiate SPAs and JAMstacks. AFAIK SPAs are almost always also backed with some API. What's the difference then?

Comment: Most SPAs would qualify as JAMstacks, although one can think of some JAMstacks not being SPAs. If your SPA relies on getting some sort of static (pre)render from the server, then it would not be JAMstack. Think of JAMstack as an extremely pure SPA. Mind you, I do not use JAMstack term every day, I think SPAs are easier to grasp.